# R Dynamically build "list" in data.table (or ddply)

Tags: r, data.table, plyr, aggregation

My aggregation needs vary among columns / data.frames. I would like to pass the "list" argument to the data.table dynamically.

As a minimal example:

```
require(data.table)
type <- c(rep("hello", 3), rep("bye", 3), rep("ok",3))
a <- (rep(1:3, 3))
b <- runif(9)
c <- runif(9)
df <- data.frame(cbind(type, a, b, c), stringsAsFactors=F)
DT <-data.table(df)
```

This call:

```
DT[, list(suma = sum(as.numeric(a)), meanb = mean(as.numeric(b)), minc = min(as.numeric(c))), by= type]
```

will have result similar to this:

```
    type suma     meanb      minc
1: hello    6 0.1332210 0.4265579
2:   bye    6 0.5680839 0.2993667
3:    ok    6 0.5694532 0.2069026
```

Future data.frames will have more columns that I will want to summarize differently. But for the sake of working with this small example: Is there a way to pass the list programatically?

I naïvely tried:

```
# create a different list
mylist <- "list(lengtha = length(as.numeric(a)), maxb = max(as.numeric(b)), meanc = mean(as.numeric(c)))"
# new call
DT[, mylist, by=type]
```

With the following error:

```
1: hello
2:   bye
3:    ok
mylist
1: list(lengtha = length(as.numeric(a)), maxb = max(as.numeric(b)), meanc = mean(as.numeric(c)))
2: list(lengtha = length(as.numeric(a)), maxb = max(as.numeric(b)), meanc = mean(as.numeric(c)))
3: list(lengtha = length(as.numeric(a)), maxb = max(as.numeric(b)), meanc = mean(as.numeric(c)))
```

Any hints appreciated! Best regards!

PS sorry about these `as.numeric()`, I could not quite figure out why, but I needed them for the example to run.

**Minor edit** inserted columns / before data.frame in initial sentence to clarify my needs.

Comment: if you provide vector inputs to `cbind`, the result would be a `matrix`. And since matrix can not hold both `character` and `numeric` arguments, every vector other than `type` will be converted to `character`. Instead you should do: `data.frame(type,a,b,c, stringsAsFactors=F)`. Even better, you can directly use `data.table(type, a, b, c)`,

Comment: you mean to say your `aggregation needs` vary **amongst the columns** of `data.table/data.frame`? What you say and what you show aren't quite the same. Because later you talk about "future data.frames will have more columns".

Comment: @Arun The answer is yes. It is more useful/accurate to characterize them as varying amongst the columns. Will make a small edit about that. Thanks for pointing out the needless/counterproductive use of cbind as well !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way is to use `.SDcols` to group the columns for which you'd like to perform the same operations together. Let's say that you require columns `a,d,e` to be summed by `type` where as, `b,g` should have `mean` taken and `c,f` its median, then,

```
# constructing an example data.table:
set.seed(45)
dt <- data.table(type=rep(c("hello","bye","ok"), each=3), a=sample(9), 
                 b = rnorm(9), c=runif(9), d=sample(9), e=sample(9), 
                 f = runif(9), g=rnorm(9))

#     type a          b         c d e         f          g
# 1: hello 6 -2.5566166 0.7485015 9 6 0.5661358 -2.2066521
# 2: hello 3  1.1773119 0.6559926 3 3 0.4586280 -0.8376586
# 3: hello 2 -0.1015588 0.2164430 1 7 0.9299597  1.7216593
# 4:   bye 8 -0.2260640 0.3924327 8 2 0.1271187  0.4360063
# 5:   bye 7 -1.0720503 0.3256450 7 8 0.5774691  0.7571990
# 6:   bye 5 -0.7131021 0.4855804 6 9 0.2687791  1.5398858
# 7:    ok 1 -0.4680549 0.8476840 2 4 0.5633317  1.5393945
# 8:    ok 4  0.4183264 0.4402595 4 1 0.7592801  2.1829996
# 9:    ok 9 -1.4817436 0.5080116 5 5 0.2357030 -0.9953758

# 1) set key
setkey(dt, "type")

# 2) group col-ids by similar operations
id1 <- which(names(dt) %in% c("a", "d", "e"))
id2 <- which(names(dt) %in% c("b","g"))
id3 <- which(names(dt) %in% c("c","f"))

# 3) now use these ids in with .SDcols parameter
dt1 <- dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by="type", .SDcols=id1]
dt2 <- dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by="type", .SDcols=id2]
dt3 <- dt[, lapply(.SD, median), by="type", .SDcols=id3]

# 4) merge them.
dt1[dt2[dt3]]

#     type  a  d  e          b          g         c         f
# 1:   bye 20 21 19 -0.6704055  0.9110304 0.3924327 0.2687791
# 2: hello 11 13 16 -0.4936211 -0.4408838 0.6559926 0.5661358
# 3:    ok 14 11 10 -0.5104907  0.9090061 0.5080116 0.5633317
```

If/when you have many many column, making a list like the one you've might be cumbersome.

Comment: This approach will actually mesh perfectly with my workflow. Thanks for reading _around my words and through my mind_.

Comment: For those reading this far, who may not be familiar with the `.SD` symbol (or data.table for that matter): datatable-faq 2.1 has a very good explanation. `.SDcols` is documented in the data.table help file.

Answer (score 10):

This is explained [FAQ 1.6](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf)  what you are looking for is `quote` and `eval`

something like

```
 mycall <- quote(list(lengtha = length(as.numeric(a)), maxb = max(as.numeric(b)), meanc = mean(as.numeric(c))))

 DT[, eval(mycall)]
```

After a bit of head-banging, here is a very ugly way of constructing the call for ddply using `.()`

```
myplyrcall <- .(lengtha = length(as.numeric(a)), maxb = max(as.numeric(b)), meanc = mean(as.numeric(c)))

do.call(ddply,c(.data = quote(DF), .variables = 'type',.fun = quote(summarise),myplyrcall))
```

You could also use `as.quoted` which has an `as.quoted.character` method to construct using `paste0`

```
myplc <-as.quoted(c("lengtha" = "length(as.numeric(a))", "maxb" = "max(as.numeric(b))", "meanc" = "mean(as.numeric(c))"))
```

This can be used with data.table as well!

```
dtcall <- as.quoted(mylist)[[1]]


DT[,eval(dtcall), by = type]
```

`data.table` all the way.

Comment: +1 Yes this is the idiomatic way.  The `eval` here is treated specially by `data.table` and `j` is optimized even though it's dynamic.

Comment: OMG! You are right... right there in the FAQ! Thanks for the solutions. Nice to see one that work under both plyr and data.table.

Comment: How can I maintain preexistent cols with   DT[, eval(mycall)] ?

Answer (score 7):

Another method (supporting the use of `paste` or `paste0` to build the expression):

```
expr <- parse(text=mylist)
DT[, eval( expr ), by=type]
#-------
    type lengtha      maxb     meanc
1: hello       3 0.8265407 0.5244094
2:   bye       3 0.4955301 0.6289475
3:    ok       3 0.9527455 0.5600915
```

Comment: +1 Small comment that `parse` will be evaluated here on each iteration (the same `parse` each time, wastefully). So it's faster to take that outside the loop and use the pre parsed expression in `j`. Either `q=parse(text=...)` or `q=quote(...)` before the DT query are ok. That then allows `data.table` to _optimize_ the `j` query. It only optimizes (changes the `j` expression) once before grouping; it can't optimize if the `parse` is inside `j`.

Comment: Edited to incorporate this improvement.

Answer (score 5):

I find it worrysome that apparently `eval` is part of the answer. From your question it is not clear to me, if and why you really want to do what you claim to want. Thus I demonstrate here that you can also use a function:

```
fun <- function(a,b,c) {
  list(lengtha = length(as.numeric(a)), 
          maxb = max(as.numeric(b)), 
         meanc = mean(as.numeric(c)))  
}

DT[, fun(a,b,c), by=type]

    type lengtha      maxb     meanc
1: hello       3 0.8792184 0.3745643
2:   bye       3 0.8718397 0.4519999
3:    ok       3 0.8900764 0.4511536
```

Comment: @Arun Your second statement is true, but I don't know if it makes sense to keep playing Guess-What-OP-Needs ...

Comment: +1 But the function call will create its own environment for each call, iiuc. The `eval` approach may be preferred for speed because `data.table` evals the expression directly in a static environment which `data.table` creates internally.  The `eval` call itself isn't `eval`'d. That is stripped off leaving the expression itself, which is then optimized before being `eval`'d by a C level eval by the grouping code. How much difference it makes of course depends. The function call is a nice syntax and that can often trump speed.

Comment: @MatthewDowle Thank you for the clarification. I'm always learning something new about data.table.