# How can I assign a variable's value to column name in plyr?

Tags: r, variables, plyr, r-colnames

Is there any way to assign a variable's value to the resultant column name in plyr?

So in this code:

```
column_name <- 'total'
df <- data.frame(a=c('a','b'), b=c(1,2))
ddply(df, .(a), summarise, column_name=sum(b))
```

As you know, this spits out a data frame which consists of variables `a` and `column_name`. However, what I want to get it is variables `a` and `total`, where `total` is assigned dynamically by a variable's value, since actually, I want to process it inside a loop, that I can't specify it directly inside ddply function.

For you information, this code doesn't work.

```
ddply(df, .(a), summarise, get(column_name)=sum(b))
```

Is there any solution to deal with it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721592/r-dynamically-build-list-in-data-table-or-ddply may be useful to point you in a direction.

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways:

```
> column_names <- c('total', 'latot')
> df <- data.frame(a=c('a','b'), b=c(1,2))
> 
> # temporal variable
> for (cn in column_names) {
+   ret <- ddply(df, .(a), summarise, ..x=sum(b))
+   ret <- rename(ret, c(..x = cn))
+   print(ret)
+ }
  a total
1 a     1
2 b     2
  a latot
1 a     1
2 b     2
> 
> # ept solution
> for (cn in column_names) {
+   print(eval(parse(text = paste0("ret <- ddply(df, .(a), summarise,", cn, "=sum(b))"))))
+ }
  a total
1 a     1
2 b     2
  a latot
1 a     1
2 b     2
> 
> # dynamic generation of call
> for (cn in column_names) {
+   args <- alist(df, .(a), summarize, sum(b))
+   names(args) <- c("", "", "", cn)
+   print(do.call("ddply", args))   
+ }
  a total
1 a     1
2 b     2
  a latot
1 a     1
2 b     2
```

Comment: Actually, I first went with eval and replaced it later with rename function, as I have a pathological hatred for calling either eval or do.call. Just wanted to know if it's feasible in one line. Thanks for the response though.