# Filtering rows by a criteria defined by variables

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I've the following `data.table`

```
structure(list(val1 = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3), val2 = c(4, 5, 6, 4, 2, 4, 5)), .Names = c("val1", "val2"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0xedae28>)
```

What I would like to do is filter the rows in it based on a criteria defined by other variables. For example, I might want all rows that have `val1 >= 1`. This is easily done as

```
x[val1 > 1,]
```

However, I want to be able to specify the column name (i.e. either `val1` or `val2`) as a variable and the filter value as a variable. I tried

```
cname = 'val1'
cutoff = 1
x[(cname >= cutoff),] # Try 1
x[(cname) >= (cutoff),] # Try 2
x[eval(cname > cutoff),] # Try 3
```

but it just gave back the original `data.table`.

Comment: List of related questions, though all of the answers are super long and/or don't use `get`, which is simplest: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24833247/1191259

Comment: @Frank, you actually took the time to read through that linked question? :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto Not quite, but more than I should have :) I had a feeling this was a dupe, but I like this Q&A much better than any of those. Here's my own question on the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19276194/1191259 I think everyone has asked this at some point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `get`:

```
x[get(cname) > cutoff,]
#    val1 val2
# 1:    2    5
# 2:    3    4
# 3:    4    2
# 4:    5    4
# 5:    3    5
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `eval` with `as.name` or `as.symbol`

```
x[eval(as.name(cname)) > cutoff]
#    val1 val2
#1:    2    5
#2:    3    4
#3:    4    2
#4:    5    4
#5:    3    5
```